# One DLL unites them all - CMAKE,

Tags: dll, plugins, cmake

i stumbled on a problem.. i would like to create a library from:

- 3 hpp (2 class.hpp, 1 main.hpp)
- 3 cpp (2 class.cpp, 1 main.hpp)

The library should have ".xpl" as ending ( Xplane10 Plugin) and depends on ROS, STD and my own Mathematics lib which i all linked against the .xpl 
Iam new to CMake and Software Design at all..i just tried to change a working cmake which creates an .exec

"if(NOT("" STREQUAL "${MODULE_HEADERS}" OR "" STREQUAL "${MODULE_SOURCES}"))

```
foreach(plugin ${MODULE_PLUGIN_SOURCES} ${MODULE_HEADERS})
get_filename_component(CPP ${plugin} NAME_WE)
set(PLUGIN_NAME "${MODULE_NAME}_${CPP}")
add_library(${PLUGIN_NAME} SHARED ${MODULE_SOURCES} ${HEADER_MOC} ${plugin})

target_link_libraries(${PLUGIN_NAME} ${MODULE_LIBRARIES})
if(NOT ("" STREQUAL "${MODULE_DEPENDENCIES}"))
add_dependencies     (${PLUGIN_NAME} ${MODULE_DEPENDENCIES})
else ()
message("no dependencies.. Are you sure? ")
endif(NOT ("" STREQUAL "${MODULE_DEPENDENCIES}"))

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES SUFFIX "")
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS 

"${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} ${XPLANE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
set_target_properties(${PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${XPLANE_PLUGIN_DIR}" )
set_target_properties(${PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES 
LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${XPLANE_PLUGIN_DIR}" )
set_target_properties(${PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "${PLUGIN_OUTPUT_FILENAME}")
endforeach()

else(NOT ("" STREQUAL "${MODULE_HEADERS}" OR "" STREQUAL "${MODULE_SOURCES}"))
message("${MODULE_NAME}: No source files  available: Plugin will NOT be created!\n" FATAL_ERROR)
endif(NOT ("" STREQUAL "${MODULE_HEADERS}" OR "" STREQUAL "${MODULE_SOURCES}"))
```

Link to another Forum where i asked a similar question: 
http://forums.x-plane.org/index.php?/forums/topic/113887-compile-linux-with-classes-and-cmake/#comment-1109097

Comment: It's not clear to me what your actual _question_ is.

Comment: I compile a X-Plane plugin. It should be like a .dll and iam not sure how to get it done. My compiler doenst complain but Xplane does: "vtable for Draw::Objects::CSensor"
And i don't know why..

Comment: Try using the `MODULE` flag to `add_library()` instead of `SHARED`.